# Set background of div using flex

Tags: css, reactjs

i am trying to develop a movie portal using react js. I am trying to display the movie poster, and the movie details adjacent to it.

I am using flex, but am encountering an issue with the output. The movie details are being pushed to an extreme end, and i am unable to figure out the reason.
I am trying to get the *"The Dark Knight"*  adjacent to the poster.
This is the output screenshot
[image: output]
my Js code is as follows,

```
dialogContent: (backgroundUrl) => ({
    backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), url(${backgroundUrl}) `,
    backgroundSize: 'cover',
            overflow: 'hidden',
    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
    backgroundSize: '100%',
    height: '33%',
    minHeight: 400,
    color: 'white',
    padding: 10
  }),

  poster: () => ({


    padding:5,
    width:'100%',
    margin:"auto"
  }),

  text:() =>({

    color:"white"
  }),

  main:() =>({
    backgroundColor: "black",
    display: "flex"
  })
}

class MovieDisplay extends Component {
    render() {
      //console.log(this.props);
      const {movie} = this.props.location.state.movie;
      return (
        <div style={styles.main()}>
            < div style={styles.poster()}>
              <img src={movie.poster_path} />
            </div>



            <div style={styles.dialogContent(movie.backdrop_path)}>
              <h1 style={styles.text()}>{movie.original_title}</h1>
              <h2 style={styles.text()}>{movie.popularity}</h2>
            </div>

            <div >
              <h5 style={styles.text()}> more content would be updated soon</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

Can anyone help figure out the reason?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try posting the HTML output.

Comment: Maybe try using justify-content, justify-items or justify-self

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to add another inside `main` container, this way you have better control over the poster and movie information spacing. You should also add some justification/alignment to your flex styling, otherwise the child elements will float to the ends of the flexed container (As seen in your example).

Add the below to your styles.

```
main:() =>({
  backgroundColor: "black",
  alignItems: 'center'
}),

/*add this style*/

innerMain: () =>({
   display: "flex",
}),
```

And then in your `MovieDisplay` component, write this.

```
<div style={styles.main()}>
      <div style={styles.innerMain()}> 

        ...

       <div style={{width: 100 + '%'}}>
          <h5 style={styles.text()}> more content would be updated 
          soon
          </h5>
        </div>


      </div>
<div>
```

Edit: I've added a [codepen](https://codepen.io/macro6461/pen/BaazYdr) to demonstrate what these styles will accomplish. More styling (like for the poster image) might be required but this is the general layout of what you're looking for.

I also added a `minWidth` of 200 to the `dialogContent` and made the `div` containing `more content...` have a width of 100% to fill the remaining space.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1puuE9163xRsG1b-mxLASovnyKGzVfiHk/view?usp=sharing       This link has the output. The problem is i want the second div extended to the rest of screen

Comment: @RakshithJk I've edited the original post and added a codepen. It appears to achieve the layout your looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the poster style set to width of 100% and margin of 'auto'.

```js
poster: () => ({


    padding:5,
    // width:'100%', <-- Try changing this by either removing it or setting to 'auto' or a smaller value
    // margin:"auto" <-- Get rid of this
  })
```

Comment: Since the overall container is flexed this won't work, as the margins will adjust to the flex.

Comment: Oops, missed that. Edited the answer to properly reflect a correct solution. Thanks.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1puuE9163xRsG1b-mxLASovnyKGzVfiHk/view?usp=sharing       This link has the output. The problem is i want the second div extended to the rest of screen